# How to get result count role on behalf of created?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[
  {
    "_id": '1',
    "role":'admin',
    "created":"0",
  },
   {
    "_id": '2',
    "role":'vendor',
    "created":"1",
  },
   {
    "_id": '3',
    "role":'cus',
    "created":"1",
  },
  {
    "_id": '4',
    "role":'cus',
    "created":"1",
  },
  {
    "_id": '5',
    "role":'admin1',
    "created":"1",
  },
  {
    "_id": '6',
    "role":'support',
    "created":"5",
  },
  {
    "_id": '7',
    "role":'support',
    "created":"5",
  },
]
```

Would like to this type of result
Thanks in Advance

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    created: "admin",
    counts: [
      {
        role: "vendor",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        role: "cus",
        count: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    created: "admin1",
    counts: [
      {
        role: "support",
        count: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You really need to be clear(why does your o/p doesn't have admin1 in counts array for created = admin ? Also your question is very confusing at first needs to be properly elaborated), this question has already been asked & has - votes :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547929/how-to-get-result-from-this-array-to-count-role-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can group by role and count created using this query.

```
db.<yourCollectionName>.aggregate ( { $group : { _id: "$role" , count: { $sum:1 } } })
```

Above query returns **output** like this...

```
{ "_id" : "cus", "count" : 2 }
```

Another variation of aggregation is..

```
db.counts.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$role", count: { $sum:1 }, Data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }  }]).pretty()
```

Above query returns **output** like this...

```
{
    "_id" : "cus",
    "count" : 2,
    "Data" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5db368e9d130deb5c19f35c8"),
                    "role" : "cus",
                    "created" : "1"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5db36913d130deb5c19f35c9"),
                    "role" : "cus",
                    "created" : "1"
            }
    ]
```

}

Comment: i want with whose created group by role {
    _id: 1,
    created: "admin",
    counts: [
      {
        role: "vendor",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        role: "cus",
        count: 2
      }
    ]
  },